# How do I ask nohup not to redirect stderr to stdout if it is detached from terminal?

Tags: linux, stdout, stderr, nohup

This question looks naive but I can't find the answer after half an hour of intensive searching. Basically I do not want stderr messages to sneak into my result file.

```
$nohup ./a.out | gzip -c > result.txt.gz 2>log.txt &
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
$zcat result.txt.gz
this is stderr output.
this is stdout output.
```

The a.out file was compiled from the following test.c by "cc test.c",

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stderr, "this is stderr output.\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "this is stdout output.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But I do not want stderr message to be in the result file result.txt.gz. It should be in log.txt but that file is empty. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error redirection actually applies to the `gzip` command, not `/.a.out`. What you're looking for is `./a.out 2> log.txt | gzip -c > result.txt.gz`.

Comment: Thank you!, "nohup ./a.out 2> log.txt | gzip -c > result.txt.gz &" worked.

Answer (score 1):

@fireshadow52 already posted a working solution, but I wanted to add some details.

A pipe connects the `stdout` of one process to the `stdin` of another. That is, it doesn't pipe `stderr` of the first command to the `stdin` of the second one. That means, as far as `nohup` is concerned, in the original command

```
nohup ./a.out | gzip -c > result.txt.gz 2>log.txt &
```

`stderr` of `./a.out` is still connected to the terminal, so `nohup` takes care of the redirection for you and any output on `stderr` gets redirected to `nohup.out`. If `stdout` or `stderr` had still been output to the terminal, that would've (possibly) interfered with the output of other commands sharing the terminal. From `man nohup`:

> If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from an unreadable file. If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise. If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output.  To save output to FILE, use 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.

With this in mind, it becomes clear that you need to redirect `stderr` *before* the pipe and end up with @fireshadow52's solution:

```
nohup ./a.out 2> log.txt | gzip -c > result.txt.gz &
```

As a slight variation of the accepted answer, one could also use process substitution instead of a pipe (although I'd argue the latter is more readable):

```
nohup ./a.out 2> log.txt > >(gzip -c > result.txt.gz) &
```

In this case, you want to redirect `stderr` and `stdout` to different destinations, but if you want all output to go through a pipe, just redirect `stderr` to `stdout` before the pipe:

```
nohup ./a.out 2>&1 | gzip -c > result.txt.gz 2>log.txt &
```